# Concatenated jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have to solve the following problem:
I have a job A in Jenkis. In one of the stages another Job B is started by the "job build" command.

For Job A to finish, it needs to wait for Job B to finish.

The problem is that Job B does not start because it is waiting for Job A to finish.

I'm using pipeline script in all Jobs.

I imagined that using the command " ***build job: 'my Job', propagate: true, wait: true***" Jenkins would start Job B and after completion of B, it would return to complete Job A

[workflow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqVK2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you just have one executor configured in your Jenkins Server/Slave. Hence Multiple builds are unable to run at the same time, which causes your deadlock.

In order to increase the executor count follow the following instructions. If you are just using the master to build. Go to `Dashboard > Manage Jenkins >  Configure` and increase the executor count.

[image]

If you have slaves go to `Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Manage nodes and clouds` click on the edit icon on the Slave and increase the executor count(more than 1) for slaves.

[image]